# From an Active Directory Domain Controller, how to remove a Computer from the Domain with Powershell?

Tags: windows, active-directory, powershell

I need to remove the local computer I'm logged in to an AD domain joined beforehand, and this with powershell, non-interactively.

I have not found any thread about it, so I wanted to create one to help others with a self-answered question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I don't see how the title isn't clear enough to pinpoint the problem, but I've added a sentence in the post body.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just have to use the command (from the domain controller):

```
Remove-ADComputer <computer>
```

Note that the possibly misleading, similarly named command `Remove-Computer` is for locally leaving a domain (i.e. to be run from the computer that has to leave the domain)